# Server Log Format

Tags: apache-2.2, squid, log-files, cache, varnish

I'm trying to understand this server log line from cache_access.log.  What does each field represent, specifically why are there three IPs listed and what does each represent?

```
[HIT - - - -] 1.1.1.0, 1.1.1.2 (1.1.1.3) - - [25/Apr/2014:00:30:02 +0000]  "GET /page/content HTTP/1.1" 200 1721 "http://www.url.com/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/34.0.1847.116 Safari/537.36"
```

Comment: This is the cache access log from which utility ?

Comment: Varnish, maybe? It's probably the client IP, the cache server IP, and the app server IP.

Answer (score 0):

From the date onwards it looks like a standard Apache combined format.

```
%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"
```

Can find what each field is here: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_log_config.html

Not sure what the cache fields at the beginning are.

Comment: How does %h have 3 different values in the example John has given?